# HDMI Simulate unplugging with Microcontroller

Tags: esp32, hdmi

I want to interrupt an HDMI Connection with an ESP in a project of mine. I have read in some posts (eg. [Can an AND gate be used to toggle an HDMI connection?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245059/can-an-and-gate-be-used-to-toggle-an-hdmi-connection)), that you can simulate an unplugging event by just cutting the HPD pin. But in my experience this does not work (tested 1 monitor with a GTX970).

Are my devices just not complient with the HDMI standard, or am I missing something?

Comment: Which one do you want, the video card to see that monitor is unplugged, or the monitor to see it is unplugged?

Comment: The GPU is just for testing, the source is gona be a Sony a7.The end result should be a black screen, until my ESP says otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HPD is pulled up with a resistor in the sink with +5V from the source. The +5V also  pulls up the DDC signals.

**The sink can force a replug event by pulling HPD low on its side**. The source will detect this, and re-initiate the DDC discovery and linkup.

However, if the source does this (that is, pull down HPD), the sink may not detect it. And if the HPD is merely disconnected at the source, the sink will definitely not see it.

Instead, **the source can initiate unplug/replug by disconnecting +5V**. The sink will definitely see this and assume an unplug. On reconnecting 5V, the sink will detect that event and power up, and eventually HPD will go high via the sink-side pull-up. The host then detects HPD low-to-high and sees that, triggering the linkup sequence.

Comment: Ok, so if my devices follow the HDMI standard, disconnecting the +5V line with, say a MOSFET, I should have a black screen until I put the 5V back unto the pin?

Comment: Yes. That's how the sink detects that the source is powered up.